# backend use from matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a module where I use tensorflow object detection api. Well, I came up with the situation where the original tensorflow code used:

```
import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

but `pyplot` was previously used in my code so the backend was automatically set to `TkAgg` as I can guess from this message:

> Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html) of `matplotlib` about backends I didn't get the difference between them. It seems that `Agg` is the general rendering engine and `TkAgg` is the backend (render+canvas)?

I want to disable the warning (by eliminating the reason not by suppressing it) and I was wondering if it makes any difference to specify

```
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

rather than

```
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

To my understanding the former seems more general and I would guess that a renderer (Agg, GTK, Cairo etc) is being chosen automatically? Is this the case? So, in my system (Ubuntu 16.04) they are equivalent? Does the former provide more portability to other platforms while the latter is stuck with Tk for example?

Comment: Do not load pylab prior to importing matplotlib. Better: do not import pylab :-)

Comment: The main difference is what happens when you call `plt.show()`. With `Agg` that would be nothing, with `TkAgg` that would be a Tk window showing the figure. If you never call `show` in your code it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: So, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest if I just use `TkAgg` in tensorflow it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Not sure what "in tensorflow" means.